# gcc clang undefined reference to `std::terminate()' with -Og

Tags: c++, exception, gcc, optimization

I have an RTOS project using C++ without exception support (`-fno-exceptions`). I'm trying to use `-Og`, but I find it gives me:

```
undefined reference to `std::terminate()'
```

This corresponds to exception handling.

The problem doesn't occur with the other `-O` options.

gcc is gcc-arm-none-eabi-7-2018-q2-update

Does `-Og` require exception handling for some reason?

**Update**

The trigger for this error can be the `noexcept` keyword.

It's an interesting conflict. Code is trying to say that it wants to use `std::terminate()` instead of `try`/`except` for its exceptions. Meanwhile, with `-fno-exceptions`, it isn't possible to throw an exception, because the `throw` will be a compile time error. So that might lead someone to think `noexcept` is ignored if `-fno-exceptions` is specified.

In my project which has no 'throw' statement at all, somehow there are particular points of seemingly innocent code that result in the compile error. Removing `noexcept` at the erroring locations causes the project to build and run properly.

If I make a small project I can't yet reproduce it.

Comment: It' s not about exception handling, it's just that when you use debugging, gcc likely falls back to `std::terminate` if something wrong is detected (instead of simply ignoring it) and this version of GCC doe not seem to provide a definition for it.

Comment: Could you provide a MCVE that reproduces this link error?

Comment: It does not always correspond to exception handling. Present your [MCVE].

Comment: FWIW this kind of seems like a toolchain oversight to me

Comment: Another detail, this is an RTOS project without a CRT that you'd find in Linux for example. Thus no std:: at all, but it has C++. Maybe if I have some time I will work out a hello world that demonstrates the problem.